# Interested in making a java script for Gaussian time stamps

Tags: java, windows, timestamp, gaussian

I'm looking for help with a script that I've been thinking about. 
I'm looking to make a time stamp generator with a `Gaussian` aspect to it, the goal is to produce a weekly botting schedule while keeping play times in the norm.

As I'm extremely new to programming in general this is a huge learning curve for me... but only one way to learn :).

```
                        MEAN, SD  Quantiles 5%,25%,50%,75%,95%    
 - Session Time (HR)  :  2.8, 1.8  (0.4, 1.0, 1.8, 3.0, 5.5)
 - Daily Session Count:  1.7, 0.9  (1.0, 1.1, 1.4, 2.1, 3.3) 
 - Daily Playtime (HR):  3.7, 2.8  (0.5, 1.6, 3.1, 5.1, 8.8)
```

[generate normal distributed timestamps within a range [0,x]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828738/generate-normal-distributed-timestamps-within-a-range-0-x)

I have found this awesome page on the same topic but I lack the experience to put it all together. I'm using a client starter and pulover's macro for the rest of the project.

Any advise or direction would be awesome! 
Thanks guys :)

Comment: I'am sorry, but StackOverflow is not a tutorial site, you should take a look at the [ask] page and take the [tour] in order to understand what we do here. Basically SO is here when you already started your project, tried, failed, can't figure out the solution, and want some help, you can then come here with a [mcve], but this is not a place to teach/learn from scratch, there is plenty of tutorials on the web :/.

Comment: my advise: if you are, as you say: "extremely new to programming", stop. Learn the basics first. Don't assume because the task seems small, it's simple. Don't assume you'll learn anything by copy-pasting code from other people. Learn the basics and work yourself up from there.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).